# What is the correct syntax for dynamic property stylesheets in PyQt6?

Tags: python, css, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I've been trying to set the stylesheet of some QWidgets using dynamic properties but I keep getting a SyntaxError. The syntax in the documentation does not seem to work for me, ideas?

This is what I have at the moment:

```
QLineEdit[notApplicable=True] {background-color:gray}
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) uses *quotes* around the value, also, `true` is lowercase (as bools in javascript): `QLineEdit[notApplicable="true"] { ... }`.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I already tried the documentation syntax and this was me trying different syntax trying to get it to work. The only other issue I can think of is _where_ that line should be? I currently have it in my top-level python file, with the code that launches the `QApplication`.

Comment: Please provide a valid [mre].